# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock')

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-theme

I'm getting two errors in my compiler at runtime stating:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock').    AndroidManifest.xml /ProxyDroid/bin line 18 Android AAPT Problem
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\aswann\Desktop\proxydroid-master\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist   ProxyDroid      Unknown Android Packaging Problem

I'm not sure exactly why this might be happening. I've updated my min SDK to 11 as suggested by other users who have experienced this issue however it is still occuring. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.proxydroid"
    android:versionCode="53"
    android:versionName="2.7.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="ProxyDroid"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AppManager"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BypassListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FileChooser"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <service
            android:name=".ProxyDroidService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".ProxyDroidWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="org.proxydroid.ProxyDroidWidgetProvider.PROXY_SWITCH_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/proxydroid_appwidget_provider" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you referenced the actionbar sherlock library project properly

Comment: The only thing I have done is download and import ProxyDroid from github (it is fresh out of the box so to speak) 

https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid

Comment: but you are using `Theme.Sherlock` so you need to download `actionbarsherlock`. Does the  `ProxyDroid` reference actionbarsherlock??

Comment: Yes... but shouldn't it be included in the source code already?

Comment: not sure coz i have not tried ProxyDroid try downloading actionbar sherlock and reference the same in your android project. see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

ProxyDroid has a dependance library which is ActionBarSherlock. You can download it here : http://actionbarsherlock.com/